# Stop time from saying 07 minutes and just 7 in Pyttsx3

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx

```
import pyttsx3
import time

time = time.strftime("%M minutes past %I")

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('rate',200)
engine.say("Hi Tom");
engine.say("The time is" + time);
engine.runAndWait();
```

When running this it will say "Hi Tom, the time is 07 minutes past 10" for example and will say a 0 in front of the minutes if its between 0-9 but 10-59 its says it normally. Is there a way to remove the 0 from being said?

Comment: I don't is possible while using strftime

Comment: @gtosto only issue there then is that the engine.say requires a string for the time

Answer (score 0):

Could this be useful

```
t = time.localtime()
   ...
engine.say('The time is %d minutes past %s' % (t.tm_min,t.tm_hour))
```